# getblockchaininfo timeout using API only

Tags: python, bitcoin-cli

Thanks in advance.
If I call getblockchaininfo through bitcoin-cli it just works. It might take a while but it works all the time.
If I call it from within a Python Script

```
from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
...
# create a connection to local Bitcoin Core node
p = RawProxy()
...
info = p.getblockchaininfo()
...
```

then 8 out of 10 times it breaks...

```
~$python .bitcoin/blockheigh.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".bitcoin/blockheigh.py", line 58, in <module>
    info = p.getblockchaininfo()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 296, in <lambda>
    f = lambda *args: self._call(name, *args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 229, in _call
    response = self._get_response()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 254, in _get_response
    http_response = self.__conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

How can I force it to wait for the response?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to use the socket `settimeout()` method before attempting the `connect()` so you wait for the response.

Comment: Is `settimeout()` part of `RawProxy`?
I can't find it

Comment: This is a good question. How do I set a timeout when I use a library that is doing the `connect()`?